# Bug in Javascript fix for IE-placeholders

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, validation

I recently [coded a form](http://plus-wuustwezel.be/index.php?page=lid-worden) with [JQuery Validation](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) in it. Because I use the `placeholder` method in my input-fields and IE doesn't support these all the way, I use a [patch](http://www.plus-wuustwezel.be/includes/js/placeholder.js) for displaying the placeholders in IE properly.

It all does work, but when you open de website in IE, you'll see the JQuery Validation is activated immediately when I open the page, which is clearly not the point. So I'm thinking this is some kind of bug. I've looked in the .js file, but my JS skills are not so good, so I'm wondering what this bug could be...
Someone with an idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="abc"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$( function() {
  $('[placeholder]').on({

  focus: function() {
    if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder') ) {
       $(this).val(''); 
    } 
  },

  blur: function(){
      if( !$(this).val() ) {
          $(this).val( $(this).attr('placeholder') );
       }

   } 

 } ).each( function() {
        $(this).val( $(this).attr('placeholder') ) ;
  } );
});
```

To run it:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">         </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      //script from above;
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" placeholder="abc"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I should replace my Placeholder.js file with this function?

Comment: I think, you can insert it everywhere where js script can run.:).  Note `$(fn)` is equal to `$(document).ready(fn)`. After jquery of course.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean... So just place this in my `<head>` and it should work in IE as well as in all other browsers without the JS-fix?

Comment: <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //paste code what i wrote here </script>
</head>

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, but for some reason, the JQuery logic is by-passed by the script. If you take a look at the page (http://goo.gl/2yHvZ), you'll see that the placeholder counts as input...

Answer (score 1):

How I deal with IE?:

- Use conditional comments to load ie.js and ie.css
- And inside these files u can take care of fixing some problems that may occur during your development.

What I suggest is, if you are using jQuery, you can create a jquery plugin `placeHolder();` and call it on all `inputs` with a classname `placeholder`:

```
jQuery.fn.placeHolder=function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var a=$(this).attr("value");

        $(this).focus(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")==a){
                $(this).attr("value","");
            }}
        );

        $(this).blur(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")==""){
                $(this).attr("value",a);
            }
        });

    });
};

$('input.placeholder').placeHolder();
​
```

[take a look on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsPwL/)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but if you take a look at the page, you'll see it's not working... http://goo.gl/2yHvZ

Comment: you are using a lot of codes there. did you tried as i wrote for you ? i'am using it on my projects for ie6+ and it works.